# How to list latest modification time of contents of some directories?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, sorting

Assume a structure like below:

```
People/
      Jimmy/
           my_Files/
                    work.txt
           report.txt
      Mohammad/
           the_work/
                    something2.sth
                    something2.sth
```

As you see, I have one directory for each clerk in the *People* directory and each clerk has a lot of files or directory in his/her directory.

I want to write a program to receive a date as input and search these directories and return which clerk hasn't modified any file after that date!

I'm using the following program to list all files:

```
files_path= list()
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(r"G:\People"):
    for filename in files:
        files_path.append(root+filename)
```

and the following program to receive the last modification time of them:

```
for single_file in files_path:
    print "last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(single_file))
    print "created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(single_file))
```

Well, both works fine! The problem is I can't manage the result to have a readable output of pairs of ***user*:*last modification time***!

Can anybody help me how handle it to have a rational output list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[time.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=strptime#time.strftime) gives you control over the formatting:

```
time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(single_file)))
```

A small helper function:

```
def format_time(seconds):
    return time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(seconds))
```

Makes it 
more approachable:

```
print "last modified: %s, created: %s" %(format_time(os.path.getmtime(single_file)),
                                         format_time(os.path.getctime(single_file)))
```

Output:

```
last modified: 13:05:56, created: 13:05:56
```